# BrowserMobProxy: How to determine IP for proxy server?

Tags: java, docker, selenium, proxy, devops

I have `BrowserMobProxy` realization in the project. This logic uses the IP address for Proxy connection and test UI web-service (Proxy used for request/response statistic saving). All worked fine before, but we restart docker and the IP address for the proxy was changed. Now I need to found a new IP address for the proxy.

Code where IP address used

```java
  public static void startProxyServer(String address) {//address = "172.17.0.2"
    if (browserMobProxy.isStarted()) {
      browserMobProxy.stop();
    }
    try {
      browserMobProxy.start(9090, Inet4Address.getByName(address)); // {1}
      useExclusivePort = browserMobProxy.getPort();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

After docker was restarting the project began fails on the line `{1}`.
I started the search for new IP on the server. Unfortunately, I can't use `ifconfig` command from the docker image since this command does not install there. So I determined the address from the server in the following way:

[image]

After I use IP 172.17.0.2 the code works well and I hoped I resolved this issue, but as it turned out I lost connection with this proxy - on the UI I got the following result:

[image]

So I totally confused:

1. All works well before the docker image was restarted
2. Old IP looks like 172.19.0.5 but the code fails with it now.
3. I "found" new IP 172.17.0.2 and code work with it.
4. I not sure I determined correct IP since all old IP was started with 172.19.0.{4,5,8}
5. I have no connection with the new IP
6. I do not know or I found the correct IP and why it suitable for code but not suitable for connection
7. The project deploys with Jenkins docker image. Browsers start on the selenium grid

#Question:

How do I need to found the correct IP that I can use for a proxy connection?

Comment: you need a way to pass in the ipaddress programatically, like with an env vairable or command line argument.

Comment: @DMart Ok. How to know which IP I need to pass?

Comment: It looks like you've set up an external proxy, yes? We'll need more details on that. This doesn't look like the typically the browsermob proxy which is simply used to manipulate requests/responses.

Comment: @DMart I do not set up a proxy myself. Maybe the docker image does that

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Why are you not using the container name?

Answer (score 2):

there are other commands with which you can find which ip your server is running on. check if you have access to any of the following

first you can try

```
netstat -an
```

which will give you all IPs your server is listening to along with what ports, and what IPs are connected on it along with the ports

if this doesn't work try this
https://dev.to/trexinc/netstat-without-netstat-inside-containers-9ak

then try

```
ip addr
```

which will give you a similar output as ifconfig

and last you can try with

```
docker inspect -f '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' containerID
```

which will give you the network interfaces of your docker

Comment: I get error: Template parsing error: template: :1:18: executing "" at <.NetworkSettings.IPAddress>: map has no entry for key "NetworkSettings" with last command. Can you clarify to me?