# BrowserMobProxy: How to use on the remote server from docker?

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob-proxy

I need to use BMP for response/request analysis (selenium using).

On the local, all works fine, but when I try to execute on the server, I get the error:

[image]

I use several variants for proxy creation:

```java
  private void startProxyServer(){
      BrowserProxySniffing.startProxyServer(BrowserProxySniffing.IP_FOR_PROXY);
      browserMobProxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT);
      browserMobProxy.newHar();
  }

class BrowserProxySniffing{
  .......

  public static void startProxyServer(String address) {
    IP_FOR_PROXY = address;
    if (browserMobProxy.isStarted()) {
      browserMobProxy.stop();
    }
    try {
      browserMobProxy.start(9090, Inet4Address.getByName(address));//variant 1 (172.17.0.2 ip using)
      browserMobProxy.start(9090);//---variant 2 (the 0.0.0.0 ip addres created)
      browserMobProxy.start(9090, Inet4Address.getByName(address));//variant 3 (localhost ip using - works fine on the local mashine)

      useExclusivePort = browserMobProxy.getPort();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
}
```

I set Capabilities in the following way:

```java
    startProxyServer(IP_FOR_PROXY);
    HashMap<String, Object> newCapabilities = BrowserProxySniffing.getProxyCapabilities();
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setCapability("seleniumProtocol", "WebDriver");

    Proxy seleniumProxy = new Proxy();
    seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy(IP_FOR_PROXY + ":" + useExclusivePort)
              .setSslProxy(IP_FOR_PROXY + ":" + useExclusivePort);

    newCapabilities.put(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,
            options.addArguments("--disable-gpu")
                    .addArguments("'--ignore-ssl-errors=yes")
                    .addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors"));
    newCapabilities.put(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
    newCapabilities.put(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
    setCapabilities(newCapabilities);
```

**Conclusions**

1. Code works fine with localhost on the local machine. So I believe the code is right
2. Code does not work with 127.0.0.1 on the server
3. Code works successful early on the server (but fails after reloading)
4. Code does not work with both localhost and 172.17.0.2 on the server

#How to use BMP on the server?

**Additional info**:

I found 172.17.0.2 in several ways:

a) `arp -a`:
[image]

b) with the /jenkins_home/selenium.xml

c) with `netstat -an`

[image]

I also used all ip's what I found with `netstat` - all of them do not suitable (fails in `browserMobProxy.start(9090, Inet4Address.getByName(address))` line, but 172.17.0.2 - success)

Comment: Why are you using the IP instead of a container name?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, Thanks for your question, but how I can use the container name for proxy creation?:
`seleniumProxy.setHttpProxy(CONTAINER_NAME+ ":" + useExclusivePort)`??

Comment: I assume that your BMP proxy and running selenium process is within in the same container? Can you explain your setup a bit. Also correct way in your case would be to use `browserMobProxy.start(9090);`